# Rails view phone number example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, formtastic

I'm trying to have a user enter their phone number in my Rails 4 app.  I'd like it to work like many of the sites that have it like this:

`1` turns into `(1`

`(111` turns into `(111)`

`(111)2` then turns into `(111) 2`

`(111) 2223` then turns into `(111) 222-3`

The end result being something like this: `(111) 222-3333`

Does the only way to do this involve using javascript on every key press for the input box, checking how many integers have been entered and putting parentheses, a space, and the dash where necessary?

EDIT:

It'd probably have to handle extra cases like where a number is pasted in.

Comment: It may not be the only way, but I would do it this way.

Comment: Would you recommend to save it as the 10 digit integer? or as the string?

Comment: It's a string -- if you're not going to add them together, or take their averages, but you are going preserve leading zeros and select the first n characters, then store it as a string with a constraint to ensure that it can only contain valid characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering your question - yes on every keypress - the most straightforward method.

Also you could make use of ready plugin like this http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ and yes pasting is also supported. Give it a try.

Comment: Wow this is an incredible, incredibly simple plugin.  Wish I know of it before.